# Inject webpack-dev-server.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I would like to inject the webpack-dev-server.js file.
However according to the documentation this should be done manually and only with the full url:

From: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#api

> Notice that [...] there is no inline mode for WebpackDevServer API.
>   `<script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>`
>   should be inserted to HTML page manually.

From: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#hot-mode

> ```
> <!-- It is important that you point to the full url -->
> <script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
> ```

What is the reason for those two points from the documentation?
Why wouldn't it be a good idea to inject a script tag like `<script src="/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>`?

---

I have also opened an issue on github: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1285

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the key is in [--inline](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#webpack-dev-server-cli). You can set it through `devServer.inline: true`. I learned recently that it injects `webpack-dev-server/client` entry automatically. In fact if you add it to your entry and use `--inline`, you'll end up with a duplicate script!

If inline is set, you need to set just `webpack/hot/only-dev-server` to your entries.

Answer (score 2):

The webpack dev server client script retrieves the address of the server it connects to from its own script tag's `src` attribute, in your case `http://localhost:8080/`.

Note that you can directly include the client script in your bundle via adding it to the entry list:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

In which case the [`webpack-dev-server/client/index.js`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/client/index.js) script (which corresponds to the `/webpack-dev-server.js` script served from the dev server) will use its resource query as the server address to connect to.

[See also the relevant snippet of code in `webpack-dev-server/client/index.js`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/fd5a85f1d0a2e10f4c25c18c3a7411a5330ade23/client/index.js#L3-7).

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I have seen this before however it doesn't answer my question.